# Unity and System.Drawing on OS X

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use System.Drawing from Mono in Unity (4.3.2) on OS X Mountain Lion. I have the following simple C# script to verify it works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Drawing;

public class DrawingTest : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(128, 128, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 4), 0, 0, 128, 128);

        bitmap.Save("/Users/username/drawing.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }

}
```

I have copied the System.Drawing.dll to my Assets/Plugins folder in the project. I also copied /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/libgdiplus.dylib to Assets/Plugins. This makes everything build (CMD-B) in Monodevelop just fine. However, when I try to run the project in Unity editor, I get this error message:

```
DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.dylib
System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor ()
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (int,int,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat)
DrawingTest.Start () (at Assets/DrawingTest.cs:9)
```

I have also added the following line:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="libgdiplus.dylib" os="osx"/>
```

to /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/etc/mono/config to try to force Unity to figure out what DLL to load. I've also set the Player Settings for the project to use ".NET 2.0" Api Compatibility Level (instead of the subset). The problem persists also if I build the project and run the standalone executable.

The same problems happen if I try to use Mono.Cairo (with different dlls, naturally). So my question is, how can I use System.Drawing or any not-enabled-by-default assembly in Unity on Mac? I would also like to eventually deploy the application to end-users, so if the standalone build requires different hacks, they would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I really can't see why you would want that library in your unity app. Perhaps if you gave a little more background on what you goal is, it would help others give you an answer.

Comment: @alex I want to render some vector graphics (filled convex polygons & bezier curves) in memory to generate textures. I'd rather use Cairo, but I thought it would be easier to get System.Drawing working. However, they both seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Homebrew package for GDI+ on macOS:

```
brew install mono-libgdiplus
```

Update: I have searched for the same problem, and found another answer, I tried and that works for me:

You can update the config file /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/X.X.X/Unity.app/Contents/MonoBleedingEdge/etc/mono/config
with the following line:
< dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/XXX/lib/libgdiplus.dylib" / >
< dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/XXX/lib/libgdiplus.dylib" / >
(XXX is your Unity version)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment I can recommend two things :

1. Have a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html). This way you could create all your shapes in 3d which would also let you visualize them in the scene. If I'm not mistaken [Vectrosity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/82) (an awesome Unity plugin) does it this way. Making a bitmap in memory and transferring coordinates from 3d space to 2d should be relatively straightforward.
2. You can just draw pixels directly to a `Texture2d` object (using [SetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html)) in memory by doing the math yourself. Unity has `Rect` shape and you could create others to suit your needs. Here are some links that should help.

[Polygon Contains](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/PolyContainsPoint)

[Procedural Primitives](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ProceduralPrimitives)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question at hand.  Yes, _possible_ solutions, but for many `System.Drawing`/`Mono.Cairo` use-cases, not viable ones.